# Can't change size of bubbles in ggplot2 when creating a world map

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a world map with bubbles whose size is derived from a variable stored in the column "Occurrences".

This is sample data:

```
         Country Year   Occurrences      lat      long
1  United States 2015     122375186 37.09024 -95.71289
2         France 2015     106748608 46.00000   2.00000
3 United Kingdom 2015      97840223 54.00000  -2.00000
4    Netherlands 2015      80930053 52.13263   5.29127
5          China 2015      74367102 35.00000 105.00000
6        Austria 2015      40521175 47.33000  13.33000
```

This is the structure of the data:

```
str(worldmapplot)
'data.frame':   240 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Country      : chr  "United States" "France" "United Kingdom" "Netherlands" ...
 $ Year         : chr  "2015" "2015" "2015" "2015" ...
 $ Occurrences  : num  1.26e+08 1.14e+08 9.87e+07 8.78e+07 7.90e+07 ...
 $ lat          : num  37.1 46 54 52.1 35 ...
 $ long         : num  -95.71 2 -2 5.29 105 ...
```

This is the code I've tried:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = mdat, aes(long, lat, group=group), fill="grey50") +
  geom_point(data= subset(worldmapplot, Country %in% Country [1:10]),
             aes(x=long, y=lat, size = "Occurrences"), col="red", show.legend = F)
```

This is the error message I get:

> Using size for a discrete variable is not advised.

[image: This is how my result looks like]

Where am I wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Change `"Occurrences"` to `Occurrences`

Comment: ha that was easy. thank you a lot